# Constructing connected complexes with prescribed homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

This exercise is taken from Munkres' Algebraic Topology book, it is in Section 6 of Chapter 1.

The problem asks you to find a $2$-dimensional complex $K$ with underlying space $|K|$ connected and $H_1(K)\simeq G_1$, $H_2(K)\simeq G_2$. Where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are finitely generated abelian groups and $G_2$ is free.

I see how one can have any finitely generated abelian group as the first homology, it is enough to take the wedge sum of $k$-fold "dunce caps" for the torsion part and adding loops to get the desired rank.

However I don't see how I can have $H_2(K)\simeq G_2$ and $H_1(K)\simeq G_1$ for general $G_1$ and $G_2$ simultaneously. The best idea I had so far was to include the wedge sum of spaces of the type

[image]

Where we identify the corners of the square and the edges in the indicated directions. If I'm not wrong this space has first homology $\mathbb{Z}$ and second homology $\mathbb{Z}$. So if the rank of $G_1$ is greater or equal than the rank of $G_2$ we are done. But this doesn't solve cases like $G_1=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $G_2=\mathbb{Z}$. How can one construct a space with those homology groups?

Comment: Take a wedge sum with spheres instead.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip oh of course! so much thinking about tori and projective planes that I forgot about spheres! :D